# SSRS Report Builder cannot use Oracle Driver on Win 10

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have installed Oracle Instant Client 32 bit Version 12.2.0.1.0 on Win10.

And referring to the instructions from Microsoft's website, I executed the commands like:

```
C:\oracle32\product\18.0.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:C:\oracle32\product\18.0.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
C:\oracle32\product\18.0.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /force /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.122.18.3
```

But when I use report builder to build datasource for oracle database, the button named "build" is not is not enabled.

Did I miss any settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I referred to this URL and solved the problem:

[referred this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

[referred these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm2Z8.jpg)